# Как отследить цвет бекграунда или градиент?

Tags: jquery, css, css3

Есть идеи как менять цвет фиксированной кнопки если бекграунд белого и черного цвета.
Например есть кнопка share белого цвета fixed, но бекграунд постоянно меняется при скроле, допустим на контрасте кнопку видно, но если бекграунд белый кнопка сливается, можно ли отслеживать цвет, те есил кнопка пересекается с темыным цветом делать ее светлее, неважно будет ли это заливка бекграунда либо градиент. 
Пример на [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/antonessential/4dgw6z9x/)
Может быть использовать как-то `mix-blend-mode: difference;`

Comment: Я такие темы дизайнеру возвращаю на доработку. но вариант с mix-blend-mode должен сработать - https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/

Comment: да mix-blend-mode: difference; прокатило!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добваить свойство `mix-blend-mode: difference;` к объекту.